# Certain String Characters To Int

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, esp8266, ide

I have a char* array which looks like this "T 20" and I'd like to extract the "20" and convert it in to an integer. I was thinking of using atoi() but it seems that function will operate on the entire string, not just the bits I want. Memory is a bit tight so is there a function similar to atoi() which allows you to specify which charters to operate on?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
char array[5] = "T 20";
int num = atoi(array+2);
```

This obviously assumes that all your strings are of the same format `"A NN"`. If not, you can try parsing it using `strtok()`. See this [excellent answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1033/17164).