# How can I control the speed and direction of dc motor at the same time (through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, joystick

I am working on a project of an arduino car it's simple really i know how to control the speed and direction using simple button but I was looking for an upgrade so I add a virtual joystick in my app now It can send 2 values first is the angle where the pointer of the joystick is which will be used to control the direction. And the distance between the center of the joystick and the pointer will be used to control the speed, problem is they are both int values how can I make the arduino differentiate between both values ? also they would be sent simultaneously over Bluetooth which might be a problem as well

Comment: look into "H bridge" modules or circuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delimiters to separate the two values you are sending over bluetooth.

Something like

```
"30,5\n"
```

instead of

```
"30\n"
"5\n"
```

On the Arduino side, read the the incoming string into a `char` array and add a `\0` after the last read character to make it a C string. The use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to parse the C string and [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or [`atof()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) to convert the parsed C strings to an `int` or `float`.

See [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1033/17164) for more information about parsing a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be the best way to use a H-bridge motor driver such as L293N. With it you can simply drive a DC motor both ways and even control it's speed.

Make the connection as shown on picture below, but connect wires of both motors to the same motor and PWM_SPEED_CTRL are channels connected to the Arduino. Don't forget to add relays between pins: 3-1, 6-2 and 11-1, 14-2, which would determine the turning direction.

If you don't understand certain thing, just ask and I'll try to reply ASAP.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer but that wasn't the point i was asking about . Still it's really helpful