# Arduino split comma separated serial stream

Tags: serial, serial-data

I'm trying to read serial data into Arduino.

I usually use a Serial to USB cable to connect to the hardware and is sending data like

```
33,Z,35.0,F,1073741.824,I,0.0,0x68
33,Z,35.0,F,1073741.824,I,0.0,0x68
33,Z,35.0,F,1073741.824,I,0.0,0x68
```

At 38400 bound rate.

I have been reading this post Splitting a comma separated string through serial (Arduino) https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/

I have tried to write something my own but none return readable data.

Any tips please?

Comment: Your device seems to use a line-oriented protocol, where each message ends with a CR and/or LF character. The first thing you should do is make sure you buffer the input in order to process one line at a time. See [Reading Serial on the Arduino](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino), by Majenko. Once you have this sorted out, follow chrisl's advice.

Comment: see https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference article, that you linked to, is about sending data over Serial, not about reading.

You can use the `strtok()` function, which can split a character buffer into tokens based on a delimiting character (the comma in your case).

First you have a buffer, where your Serial message in saved (I'm not covering the actual receiving/reading of the Serial data here, because there are tons of tutorials on the web):

```
char buffer[] = "1,2.3,4,0x56";
```

Then you can get the first token:

```
char *token1 = strtok(buffer, ",");
```

`token1` is a pointer to the start of the token. `strtok()` replaces the found delimiter (which you specify with the second parameter) with a null character. That means, that `token1` points to a null terminated C string with only the first token in it (Keep in mind that the buffer is changed with that, so it does not make any sense to try printing `buffer` after you used `strtok()`). Note, that this does not create a new buffer. It simply points to a specific place inside `buffer`.

You could also directly process it, for example convert it to an integer:

```
int token1_value = atoi(strtok(buffer, ",");
```

To get the next token, you simply again call `strtok()`, but now you provide `NULL` instead of `buffer` in the first parameter. That tells `strtok()`, that you still want to process the same buffer from the last execution.

```
float token2_value = atof(strtok(NULL, ",");
```

You can now do this, until no token is left unprocessed in the `buffer`. In that case `strtok()` returns `NULL`.

```
char *token = strtok(NULL, ",");
while(token != NULL){
    Serial.println(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

Have a look at the [C++ reference for `strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). It also includes an online editor, where you can run the provided example and play with it.