# How do I split an incoming char?

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I am sending a list of joystick positions via the serial connection to the arduino in the following format

515;520

Which would be parsed as:

x=515

y=520

How would I split these values up, and convert them to an integer?

MyReceiver:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define xBeeRxPin 10
#define xBeeTxPin 9
SoftwareSerial xBeeSerial(xBeeRxPin, xBeeTxPin);
char val;

void setup() {
  xBeeSerial.begin(38400);
  Serial.begin(38400);
}
void loop() {
  
  if(xBeeSerial.available()>0){
   val = xBeeSerial.read();
   Serial.print(val);
  }
 
}
```

My Coordinator:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define xBeeRxPin 10
#define xBeeTxPin 9
int deger1;
int deger2;
SoftwareSerial xBeeSerial(xBeeRxPin, xBeeTxPin);
void setup() { 
  
   xBeeSerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  
  deger1 = analogRead(A0);
  deger2 = analogRead(A2);
  char buf[1000];
  const char *first = " ";
  const char *second = ";";
  char val[4];
  char deger[4];

  strcpy(buf,first);
  sprintf(val,"%d",deger1); 
  strcat(buf,val);
  strcat(buf,second);
  sprintf(deger,"%d",deger2);
  strcat(buf,deger);

  Serial.print(buf);
  xBeeSerial.write(buf);  
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: Put all characters into a `char` array. Then use `strtok()` for splitting and `atoi()` for converting to integer. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is the reference for `strtok()`. You can even open the online editor with the example there (click on "Edit and run") and play with it, until you understand, how it works.

Comment: And you can look at my answer to this question. It already explains how to use `strtok()`. [Arduino split comma separated serial stream](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77081/arduino-split-comma-separated-serial-stream)

Comment: I examined but i can not. Can you help me in the code selection above?

Comment: Where in the code above are you trying to split a string? I cannot know, where you want to do that. And what do you mean by "I can not"? What exactly is the problem? Have you looked at some tutorials on `strtok()`. Have you tried yourself in the online editor in the reference, that I linked to? Is my answer to the other question not clear enough? I need to know, where exactly the problem is, so that I'm not just writing down the same stuff as in my other answer, but helping you with the problem.

Comment: I cannot directly transfer the data I get from xBee into char buffer[].