# Read Comma Separated String

Tags: programming, c++, string, serial-data, c-string

I have a string that looks like this "10.00,20.00,-50.00," in which these are angle values and they have 2 decimals and can be negative. I want to separate them into 3 separate floats. Here is my current code in which I use sscanf. All I get is 0.00 and have no idea why. Any help is truly appreciated.

```cpp
String recvString = "10.00,20.00,-50.00,";
float r,p,y;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(r);
  int result = sscanf(recvString.c_str(), "%f,%f,%f,", &r, &p ,&y);
  Serial.println(r);
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: It's not a full duplicate but it will help you understanding the problem and reason better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651012/arduino-sprintf-float-not-formatting. You can use function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/`

Comment: a comma is not whitespace ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091284/read-comma-separated-input-with-scanf#15091406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the indexOf function to find index then use the subString to get values like this:

```
String recvString = "10.00,20.00,50.00";
float r, p, y;



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.println(r);
  //recvString.toCharArray(s, recvString.length() + 1);
  //int result = sscanf(recvString.c_str(), "%f,%f,%f,", &r, &p ,&y);
  int i1 = recvString.indexOf(',');
  int i2 = recvString.indexOf(',', i1+1);
  Serial.println(i1);
  Serial.println(i2);

  String firstValue = recvString.substring(0, i1);
  String secondValue = recvString.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
  String thirdValue = recvString.substring(i2 + 1);

  Serial.println(firstValue);
  Serial.println(secondValue);
  Serial.println(thirdValue);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: definitely not this way

Comment: But it works so why not?

Comment: see the other answer

Answer (score 2):

The AVR implementation of `sscanf()` does not support parsing floating point numbers, thus you only get zeros out of it. You can't use the `%f` specifier with it. You need to convert these numbers by yourself with functions like `atof()` or similar.

Splitting a string into parts can be done many ways. You could use `sscanf()` to split up the string parts and then use something like `atof()` to actually convert to float. Or you use `strtok()` for splitting (see my answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77081/arduino-split-comma-separated-serial-stream/77082#77082)). Or you use one of the many other options, that you get, when googling for something like "Arduino split string" or "Arduino split c string".

Note: Using the `String` class in Arduino is easy for beginners, but not a good practice (dynamic allocation, heap fragmentation). Look at [Majenkos blog](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) for more information about that. Since you already used a function for C-strings, I would suggest moving completely to C-strings (which are basically only an array of `char`).